# Slideshow for the homepage. Views Slideshow or another Module?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a slideshow with pagination on my homepage. Should I use Views Slideshow or is there another Module which is flexible and will give me the ability to add a slideshow block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, adding a module for this is overkill. I prefer to create a view, add the jQuery Cycle plugin to my theme and apply the plugin to the view using just a few lines of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module http://drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic ,its nothing but the support module for views . You can customize the slideshow with thumbnail,content of slideshow,prev ,next button and pagination through view fields.

Answer (score 0):

I use EntityFieldQuery which is part of core and can be faster to work with and to run for many simple use cases like slideshows than Views - http://drupal.org/node/1343708

I personally love the carouFredSel slideshow - http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Edit: EntityFieldQuery is only part of core in D7